# Issue with openCV classifier

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

```
clf = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
clf.train(faces, IDs)
clf.save("classifier.xml")
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Training Datasets completed")
```

the problem with this code is it runs but it's incomplete.
It does not create classifier.xml and is incomplete since it does not show "Training Datasets complete" message box.

I have installed Opencv & Opencv-contrib-python
but it's not working at all.
I tried with

```
clf = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

and failed.

I expect to create a trained file model named classifier and the process needs to be complete.

Comment: you installed both modules? that's an error. remove all. install _exactly_ one. if that didn't cause the issue, it would cause other issues some other time. -- make sure you understand the result of `os.getcwd()` -- "failed" requires traceback. [mre]

Comment: pip install --force-reinstall opencv-contrib-python==4.x.x X denote version.

Comment: pip install --user opencv-contrib-python==4.x.x X denote version